# Вопрос по строкам в Java

Tags: java, строки

Пример кода:

```
String s = "abcd";
```

Тут мы явно указываем, что в переменной s хранится ссылка на объект. Сам объект неизменяемый, например, при вызове метода substring() для s,  создается новая строка (обьект).

Второй пример кода:

```
if (s.substring(1).equals("j")) {
...
}
```

Вопрос:

1. Где хранятся и хранятся ли вообше ссылки на объекты s.substring(1) и "j", так как явно мы не сохранили их в каких либо переменных.
2. Что происходит с этими строками после того как метод отработает, уничтожаются ли они сборщики мусора, так как, например, если этот if будет в теле цикла и на каждом шагу s.substring() будет создавать строки, которые !equals() между собой  (чтобы в пуле были разные строки), то это же лишняя трата памяти.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193571/how-does-java-store-strings-and-how-does-substring-work-internally

Comment: в пул записываються только новые строки. Уже существующие туда не попадут. После выполнения твоего кода в пуле появяться строки [a b c d j]

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @Roman B , Я знаю , поэтому и пояснил, что при каждом шаге если добавлять новые строки в пулл, чтобы тратилась  на это память, там не обязательно метод substring(), я просто привел его как пример

Comment: в таком случае, обычно строку розбивают на масив чаров, и проверяют методом контейнс. Я так понимаю вы хотите проверить если ли такой символ в строке?

Comment: или даже так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506105/how-can-i-check-if-a-single-character-appears-in-a-string

Comment: @Roman B, нет я не хочу проверить есть ли такой символ в строке, я просто привел в пример метод, который создает новую строку.

Comment: Вы можете сами поместить строку в пул, воспользовавшись методом `intern()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Где хранятся и хранятся ли вообше ссылки на объекты s.substring(1) и "j", так как явно мы не сохранили их в каких либо переменных.

`"j"` — литерал (строковая константа), соответственно, при загрузке класса автоматически интернируется и попадает в пул строк, где и хранится. На строку будет хранится ссылка из класса, в котором она объявлена, соответственно, она не будет доступна сборщику мусора пока сам класс не будет выгружен из виртуальной машины.

`s.substring(1)` — создает новый объект, ссылка на который нигде не хранится. Динамически созданные строки собираются сборщиком мусора, как и любые другие объекты. Кстати, при таком вызове будет выбрана строка без первой буквы, а не первая буква.

Создание новых объектов можно отследить с помощью такого кода (Динамически созданную строку можно принудительно поместить в пул, с помощью метода [`String.intern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--).):

```
String s = "hello";
//false, строка такая же, но substring создает новый объект
System.out.println(s.substring(0,1)=="h");
//false, оба раза substring создает новый объект
System.out.println(s.substring(1,2)==s.substring(1,2));
//true, получили ссылку на строку из пула
System.out.println(s.substring(0,1).intern()=="h");
//true, поместили строку в пул
System.out.println(s.substring(1,2).intern()==s.substring(1,2).intern());
```

Динамически созданные строки, помещенные в пул, хранятся в куче ([начиная с JDK7](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html)) и доступны сборщику мусора.

> Что происходит с этими строками после того как метод отработает, уничтожаются ли они сборщики мусора, так как, например, если этот if будет в теле цикла и на каждом шагу s.substring() будет создавать строки, которые !equals() между собой (чтобы в пуле были разные строки), то это же лишняя трата памяти.

В цикле каждый раз будут создаваться новые объекты, которые будут доступны сборщику мусора. Поведение для строк в данном случае аналогично поведению для любых других объектов.

Похожие вопросы на английском:

- [Garbage collection on intern'd strings, String Pool, and perm-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152560/garbage-collection-on-internd-strings-string-pool-and-perm-space)
- [Garbage collection behaviour for String.intern()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431540/garbage-collection-behaviour-for-string-intern)

Comment: Спасибо, очень хорошо объяснили.

Comment: @Vennic Пожалуйста! Успехов!